# Facebook has detected that 'App' isn't using a secure connection to transfer information

Tags: node.js, heroku, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have a nodejs app to authenticate users using Facebook. The app is deployed using Heroku. It is working fine for localhost but it does not work for the deployed site URL. [here](https://authenticate-backend.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook) How do I fix this?

[image]

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: keys.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback",
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    const { id, first_name, last_name ,name} = profile._json;
    const userData = {
      facebook_id : id,
      first_name : first_name,
      last_name : last_name,
      username : name
    };
    userModel.findOne({facebook_id:id}).then((user)=>{
        if(!user)
            new userModel(userData).save().then((newUser)=>{
                done(null,newUser)
            });
        else
            done(null,user)
    })
  }
));
```

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'))

app.get("/auth/facebook/callback",passport.authenticate("facebook", {
      successRedirect: "/success",
      failureRedirect: "/fail"
    })
);
```

Heroku Logs

```
2021-04-24T09:58:58.154550+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
2021-04-24T09:58:58.154565+00:00 app[web.1]: at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:20)
2021-04-24T09:58:58.154566+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
2021-04-24T09:58:58.154567+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
2021-04-24T09:58:58.154668+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
2021-04-24T09:59:17.992947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQCWsZz7kdnjlF6b-4UltHiCo8nvktLXI8pwtEm65SO6DbH78h6dzTvygqZkUE2eg9WVufXyLdXUgX58_65TTb54zPWXN1sdTBTMltjO3nm_49XeWBqkcYa3qLcXUV_LwS2H_v2DpMbTTpcL5o430yHsdC3J4SF4VsXEV0tQ2E6wYgh9zMVBL-b7Omj8n_vIvLPqMlAnccP8PFMZOeV8UV0b0DovUNL8dd930aL12-x1RNdlw_yvq7G3TqpKXCq64Ny-hkNsTeSRSR0qEpiWUoC_afLMi-VoU1AiFp3gCfsWSumfQcsDWvwAv1eJDY9T48b6XP0i_u8f7FnQySExnrFl" host=authenticate-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=244f274e-ae42-4560-9f8f-078dbf987f6f fwd="116.206.223.233" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-04-24T10:04:39.435159+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=authenticate-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=d30d85eb-9137-43c5-8d5f-b6bd300094f4 fwd="116.206.223.233" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=181 protocol=https
```

Comment: At what point of the authentication flow are you getting this error?

Comment: I think it is occuring in the callback section although I am not sure. https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fauthenticate-backend.herokuapp.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&client_id=968868027216417 This is where I get this popup

Comment: I do not have a facebook account so I couldn't visit the link. Are you able to actually login with facebook successfully? Are you being redirected back to you application after that? If so, are you able to provide the full url you are actually being redirected to?

Comment: Yes, when I was working on it locally I was able to log in using my Facebook and then was redirected according. Essentially after authenticating it just returns the user data using res. send.But the same does not work for the deployed version on heroku

Comment: Ok, but on the deployed version, I'm trying to pinpoint at what point the error is actually occuring. Are you at all able to login with facebook? Or are you receiving the error even before you try to do so? If you are actually able to login, then you should be redirected somewhere - and the error may be occuring at that point, If we are in this scenario, are you able to tell the actual url you are being redirected to?

Comment: Okay so I tried this in incognito and I am getting the Facebook login page but an error is shown `You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://`

Comment: As far as I know apps deployed using Heroku have https://

Comment: And if I change the callbackURL to https://auth-backend.heroku.com/auth/facebook/callback I get this error in heroku logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231541/discussion-between-satyaki-das-and-iamdranged).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds your issue has to do with the way the full callback url for the facebook strategy is being reconstructed while the application is running behind a proxy.

In the case of a relative callback url like your code specifies, the facebook strategy actually ends up calling the following function to obtain a full url - slightly simplified with just the essential bits:

```
function originalURL(req, options) {
    var trustProxy = req.app.get('trust proxy')) ? true : false;

    var isConnectionSecure = req.connection.encrypted || (trustProxy && 'https' == req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'].split(/\s*,\s*/)[0])
    var protocol = isConnectionSecure ? 'https' : 'http'
    // ...

    return protocol + '://' + host + path;
};
```

Essentially, it tries to understand whether the incoming request is transmitted over a secure channel.

- It first looks at whether the current connection is actually encrypted.
- If not, it checks if the request was forwarded by a trusted proxy where the connection between the client and the proxy is encrypted.

Only in either one of these scenarios will the protocol for the callback url be set to https.

As far as I know, Heroku uses a proxy to redirect traffic internally using regular http, so you would need to set up your app to trust it.

```
app.enable('trust proxy')
```

As I mentionned in the chat, the other issue later raised in the comments with mongoose are totally separate from the question asked.

Comment: Adding `app.enable('trust proxy')` fixed this problem for me. Thanks!